# How to modify Django models.DateTimeField type?

Tags: python, django

I am running an api server using django rest api.
I want to change 2020-01-01T00:00:00+09:00 to 2020-01-01 00:00:00 in model.

This is my model code..

```
from django.db import models 

class Data(models.Model): 
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    sensor = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    measure = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.sensor
```

And my serializer code..

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from .models import Data

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Data
        fields = ('id','time','sensor','measure')
```

lastly my view

```
from .models import Data 
from .serializers import MovieSerializer 
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class DataList(APIView):


    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Data.objects.filter(sensor=pk)
        except Data.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        dt = Data.objects.all()
        serializer = MovieSerializer(dt, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        val = request.data.values()
        if val is not None:
            for i in val:
                snippet = self.get_object(i)
                serializer = MovieSerializer(snippet, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I think **I can't modify the code of view and serialize.**
I need a way to modify the type in the model.

Thank you.

Comment: The model is not concerned with the format. The serializer determines the format.

Answer (score 0):

A model field is not concerned with the format. You can specify the format in the [**`DateTimeField`** serializer field [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield):

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    time = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    class Meta: 
        model = Data
        fields = ('id','time','sensor','measure')
```

If you want to change the format for all `DateTimeField`s, you can change the [**`DATETIME_FORMAT`** setting [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#datetime_format) `API_SETTINGS`:

```
# settings.py

# …

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
}
```

Comment: wow.. I was deeply impressed with your response. Thank you very much.